# How to make multiline label with Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I use [Eureka library](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) and i encountered a problem. I need a multiline label row but don't know how to do it. I can see only one-line with truncation label rows.

```
 class MainViewController: FormViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      form +++=

        Section()

        <<< LabelRow { row in
            row.title = "Hello World 1. Hello World 2. Hello World 3"
        }
 }
```

Comment: Please put some code here. Where is the init of the label, you can set $0.numberOfLines = 0 . This will make infinity lines.

Comment: @AltimirAntonov added code

Comment: Ok, then under row.title, add row.numberOfLines = 0 . If you accept this, tell me to make it as Answer and give me points c(:

Comment: row.cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: @AltimirAntonov thanks that works make this is as answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With `row.cell` you get the whole cell and you can customize it.

The label row should like something like this:

```
<<< LabelRow { row in
    row.title = "Hello World 1. Hello World 2. Hello World 3"
    row.cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is okay but to be better. You can use **defaultCallSetup** for your all LabelRow, TextAreaRow and others. Do like as below.

```
LabelRow.defaultCellSetup = {cell, row in
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Your_Custom_font_Name", size: 13)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellow
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .justified
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}


+++ LabelRow(){
       $0.title = "Question    :   Current Occupancy and long text goes"
    }
```

All textLabel attributes can be used just like that.

Comment: I tried setting number of lines to 0. But didnt work. Anything else to set for making the label multiline ?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not too sure what your Eureka library does, however if you want to have multi lines for your label, inside your storyboard, just change the "Lines" property to 0.

If your label is inside a `UITableViewCell`, you need set a dynamic `UITableViewCell` height.

[image]